# Copy specific columns to a new worksheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Am fairly new to excel and was wondering if there is an easier way to do a routine cut copy paste I do. I have a worksheet that looks like following:

```
Fruits    Nuts      Veggies
Apple     Walnut    Potato
Banana    Chestnut  Broccoli
```

The first row refer are headers. Is there a way to search for a row name in the worksheet 1 and once found, it copies the entire column (which contains the row name) to a new worksheet? For example, I can search for "Fruits" and it copies the entire column of Fruits. The result should look like this in the new worksheet:

```
Fruits    
Apple     
Banana
```

The if I did a search again for Nuts, the result should be the following:

```
Fruits    Nuts      
Apple     Walnut    
Banana    Chestnut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just change the Sheet1 and Sheet2 to the sheetnames you have

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FindTextAndCopyToNewWS()
Dim ws As Worksheet, targetWks As Worksheet
Dim FindString As Variant
Dim rng As Range, sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
Dim lastCol As Long, lColumn As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

FindString = InputBox("Search for value")

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
Set rng = ws.Cells.Find( _
                 What:=FindString, _
                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                 LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                 MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    Set sourceColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(rng.Column)

    Set targetWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastCol = targetWks.Cells(1, targetWks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If targetWks.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
        Set targetColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(lastCol)
    Else
        Set targetColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(lastCol + 1)
    End If

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Niclas. But what if we wanted to search and copy multiple things? Is there an excel formula we can use? Ideally, every time I use the search, the search should be added to the subsequent column of the new sheet.

Comment: So everytime you search for a fruit or veggie, then it should copy the whole column to sheet2 and add the copied copy after the existing ones?

Comment: Yes, That is correct. I modified the question to show an example of the output.

Comment: @SageMohan try it now

Comment: that woked! One last thing, since I know what columns I need to copy, is there a way to hard code those column names so that I don't have to constantly hit the search? So for example when I run the macro on sheet 1, Fruits and Vegetables should be automatically copied into the new worksheet.

Comment: You can basically do whatever you want with VBA (almost). So when you run the macro, you will have to search for something. Let's say you search for nuts, then you want it to copy nuts and the 2 other columns as well? But honestly, it is easier just to keep it as it is, so it is dynamic, and then do some error handling. So if column header (e.g. Fruits) exists in sheet2, then do not copy that column. Do you follow? :-)

Comment: I do. Thank you, that does help in understanding.

Comment: just in case, would you be able to make it into a static code? The column names are known and specific and hence the code would not require it be dynamic. So for example, we just hard code 'Fruits' and 'Vegetables' so that whenever these two columns appear of Sheet 1, they're automatically copied to sheet 2.  Thanks

Comment: It is possible, but I think you should create a new question as it is not what you originally wanted. So maybe I or another person can help you.